# Firemonkey: How can I play a video (from youtube) in my form?

Tags: delphi, video, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I don't want put a link to a video, I want show the video on my app. There is some way to do this? Please give me some direction.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a TWebBrowser component:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
   WebBrowser1.URL := 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_rTWxJepO8';
end;
```

Comment: You could also use a video player, but that would require you to also download the video entirely first, or implement your own streaming. (Unless it handles all of that.) I think this is the easiest approach.

Comment: The video player doesn't stream, it only plays local video.  The OP asked  "from Youtube".  I agree, a component solution may be easier, but you'll need to look for a 3rd party component for that; you might look at FMXexpress.

Comment: That's what I thought I said, although re-reading my comment, I now see that it's ambiguous. "I think this is the easiest approach." meaning using a web browser, NOT using the video player! Sorry for the confusion.